# How can I an Object's Property to a String in Powershell

Tags: string, object, powershell, properties

I'm pretty familiar with PHP, Javascript, etc but I'm new to Powershell.  I'm trying to get IP addresses and Mac addresses from all the computer's in an active directory.  I came across a script that gets an object with all the computer names a lists them through a foreach loop.  Inside that loop, I'm trying to run the following:

```
$colItems = GWMI -cl "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration" -name "root\CimV2" `
comp $objComputer.name -filter "IpEnabled = TRUE"
```

Obviously, this isn't working since it can't take data from the pipeline.  Is there away to take the name property and convert it into a string variable to use within the Get-WmiObject?  I've tried declaring a string variable with that $objComputer.name as the value and tried $($objComputer.name), but neither did it for me.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Joey just wondered why you deleted this: Thanks and have a good one. ?

Comment: Matt: [Behold the mighty Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need a hyphen in front of comp...

```
$colItems = GWMI -cl "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration" -name "root\CimV2" -comp $objComputer.name -filter "IpEnabled = TRUE"
```

that could be a copy and paste error...

This works for me though (using a dot):

```
$colItems =GWMI -cl "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration" -name "root\CimV2" -comp . -filter "IpEnabled = TRUE"
```

using $objComputer though you could do this

```
$objComputer = @{ "name" = "." }
```

Matt

Comment: Wow, it was a copy and paste error.  The site I got that GWMI call from had the typo and I didn't know enough to recognize it.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Get-WmiObject doesn't accept pipeline input. Altough passing $objComputer.name is perfectly valid (as long as $objComputer is an object that has a name member) you can assign the name value to a vraible and pass the variable to the ComputerName property.

```
foreach($objComputer $computers)
{
    $name = $objComputer.name
    $colItems = GWMI -cl Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -comp $name -filter "IpEnabled = TRUE"
    $colItems
    ...
}
```